# Maclaurin series for ln

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I need to find the Maclaurin series for $\ln\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} $. I found it is $\frac{x^{2n+1}}{{2n+1}}$ ,is it correct? I got the 1/2 outside and solved the maclaurin for the normal log. If it is okay how can I find a relationship between this and the maclaurin series artg.I know it is $(-1)^n$ of my series but how can I write it?

Comment: Well I found the series for the first one and I know the series for the second but I'm not sure how to get them together Is it right if i say that my first series *(-1)^n equals artan?

Comment: Looks like you have the series expansions.  You could say that in the power series expansion of two functions, for one the coefficients are alternating and the other is not, but the absolute value of the coefficients is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taylor series for $\log\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$ at $0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, because$$\begin{align}\log\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}&=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\\&=\frac12\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\right)\\&=\frac12\left(x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots-\left(-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4-\cdots\right)\right)\\&=x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5+\cdots\end{align}$$And the Taylor series for $\arctan(x)$ at $0$ is quite similar: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. That's because$$\arctan'(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

It’s very helpful to have memorized that $$\ln(u+1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}u^n}{n}$$

So taking $$u=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}-1$$

you can have

$$\ln\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}-1\right) ^n}{n}$$

Comment: Don't you find it a bit ugly?

Comment: @Botond Well José Carlos Santos has already posted his more elegant answer. The OP provides no context, and I’m just including an additional approach. The OP can simplify if desired.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}-\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}(-1)\frac{x^n}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}+\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}((-1)^{n+1}+1)\frac{x^n}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}2\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\right)=\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=:f(x)$$
And the arctan is:
$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=:g(x)$$
One relation can be:
$$\tan^{-1}(x)=-\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}}\right)$$
Or alternatively:
$$g(x)=-f(ix)$$

Answer (score 0):

As the derivative of this function is
$$\frac12\bigl(\ln(1+x)'-\ln(1-x)'\bigr)=\frac1{1-x^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}x^{2n},$$
integrating term by term, we indeed obtain
$$\ln\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\biggr)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}. $$
On the other hand, this function is also the inverse hyperbolic function
$$\arg\tanh x$$
which explains why this expansion is very close to the expansion of $\arctan x$.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, if $f(x)=\log \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$, then $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x))$. Note $\log(1+x)=\sum_{n \ge 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ and $-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{x^n}{n}$. Thus $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)=2(\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1})$.